# Headings won't change color induvidually?

Tags: html, css

I can change the color of headings when I use an overarching change, like

```
 html{
color: black
}
```

but when I keep it just on it's own, like

```
 h1{
color: black
}
```

the color won't change. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Will you please share your html code?

Comment: Why do I have a feeling that you ain't checking for updates, I mean like, text is usually black, and you set the `html` to `black`. try setting `h1`'s color to `red` and share your results

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Double-Check for typos (errors) first.

This may not be the solution but you forgot to add a trailing semi-colon `;` and AFAIK CSS is very very non-tolerant.

Do this when absolutely necessary: If you use a library, there may be a style that is interfering with yours so you may have to add `color: black !important;`, but do this when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Woah, this actually fixed it. Guess i need to be more careful! ty :)

Answer (score -1):

It should show color as red. Here's a sample JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tanvir_rahman/yd4ncg08/1/

your html will be

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

And css will be

```
h1 {
  color: red
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should, but it isn't. That's the problem.